# Looking for MANAGE button in Azure SQL Databases

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am being tasked at a new job with managing some SQL Server databases hosted in Microsoft Azure, however it appears that some changes have been made to Azure Web Interface and there is no longer a MANAGE button option shown for a specific database, can anyone explain what happened to this option, and how to bring it back in the Azure Web Interface?

Basically this option let me view the data in the columns of the database tables, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the database server with SSMS?

Comment: No not yet, the majority of my previous sql experience I worked in with sql management studio, I am relatively new to Azure, can you provide a step by step for this?

Comment: Here is a simple sample on how to connect.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-connect-to-database/

Comment: Actually thanks I know how to connect to the sql server database in SSMS, however we have a non-technical user here who liked to use the Azure Web Interface to view the data in the databases, using the MANAGE button, but now that option is gone from the Azure Web Interface, this user prefers using the Azure Web Interface over using SSMS, I am just wanting to know if the same function can be had in the Azure Web Interface to view data in the columns, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The "manage" button you are referring to was removed for the latest generation of servers (v12) for Azure SQL Database.  Using SSMS or Visual Studio is the recommended way to manage your servers going forward.  However, if you really want the old web management portal you will need to create your SQL Database on a v11 server.  You can do this in the portal in the new server blade by setting *Create V12 server* to "No".

[image]